# Return multiple values from list nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to retrieve specific keys' value from list-nested dictionaries. How to pass multiple keys into filter?

```
lst = [{'KeyA': 'Vxx', 
         'KeyB': 'Vyy', 
         'KeyC': 'Vzz'}]

val = [i['KeyA'] for i in lst if 'KeyA' in i]

print(val)
```

Desired result would be to retrive specific keys `['KeyB', 'KeyC']` and additionally morph into dataframe.

```
lst_result = [KeyB:Vyy, KeyC:Vzz]

data_frame = 
   KeyB  KeyC
0  Vyy   Vzz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, all you need is :

```
specific_keys = ['KeyB','KeyC']
pd.DataFrame(lst)[specific_keys]
```

Output:

```
   KeyB KeyC
0   Vyy  Vzz
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want the values, you might have to find them directly:

```py
TargetKeys = ['KeyB','KeyC']
lst_result = {}
for den in lst:
    for akey in den.keys():
        if akey in TargetKeys:
            lst_result[den[akey]] = den['Value']
            break
print(lst_result)
```

Preumably then `df = pd.DataFrame(lst_result)` will give you the dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my code. Added a fix.